# Как удалить строку в таблице JS?

Tags: javascript

Необходимо проработать функцию Controls.DEL

```
(function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        var createDOMElement = function (tagName = '', options = {}, parent) {
            var el = document.createElement(tagName);
            for (const key in options) {
                //console.log(key + " " + options[key]);
                el.setAttribute(key, options[key]);
            }

            parent.appendChild(el);
            return el;
        }


        var datalist = [
            {
                fio: 'Ivanov Ivan Ivanovich', email: 'ivanoff@iv.com', phone: '+380662569854'
            },
            {
                fio: 'Petrov Ivan Ivanovich', email: 'petroff@pet.com', phone: '+380662569855'
            },
            {
                fio: 'Borisov Ivan Ivanovich', email: 'boriosoff@c.com', phone: '+380662569856'
            },
        ];

        var block = createDOMElement('div', {
            'class': 'container'
        }, document.body);
        var cPannelBlock = createDOMElement('div', {
            'class': 'cPanel'
        }, block);
        var Controls = {};
        Controls.ADD = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/plus.png',
            alt: 'add element',
            title: 'Add new line',
        }, cPannelBlock);
        Controls.EDIT = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/edit.png',
            alt: 'edit element',
            title: 'edit line',
        }, cPannelBlock);
        Controls.DEL = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/del.jpg',
            alt: 'del element',
            title: 'del line',
        }, cPannelBlock);
        Controls.UP = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/up.png',
            alt: 'up element',
            title: 'up line',
        }, cPannelBlock);
        Controls.DOWN = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/down.png',
            alt: 'down element',
            title: 'down line',
        }, cPannelBlock);

        var table = createDOMElement('table', {
            class: 'editTable'
        }, block);

        var rows = [];
        var cells = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < datalist.length; i++) {
            cells[i] = [];
            rows[i] = createDOMElement('tr', {}, table);
            var tdN = createDOMElement('td', {}, rows[i]);
            tdN.innerHTML = i + 1; cells[i].push(tdN);

            var tdF = createDOMElement('td', {}, rows[i]);
            tdF.innerHTML = datalist[i].fio; cells[i].push(tdF);

            var tdE = createDOMElement('td', {}, rows[i]);
            tdE.innerHTML = datalist[i].email; cells[i].push(tdE);

            var tdP = createDOMElement('td', {}, rows[i]);
            tdP.innerHTML = datalist[i].phone; cells[i].push(tdP);


        }
        console.dir(rows);
        console.dir(cells);
        
        Controls.DEL.addEventListener('click', function(){
        
        });

    });
})()
```

Comment: От кода не понятно, где будет находиться кнопка. Для "навигации" по элементам, используйте `.closest(".selector")`, `.parentNode`, `.nextElementSibling`, `,previousElementSibling`, `.children`

Comment: Почему метод DEL создает элемент, а не удаляет согласно контексту ?  Controls.DEL = createDOMElement('img', {
            class: 'controls',
            src: 'images/del.jpg',
            alt: 'del element',
            title: 'del line',
        }, cPannelBlock);

Comment: 1) По-хорошему удалять надо не строку в таблице, а менять datalist, а уже его отображать в таблицу 2) Controls.DEL -- это у вас элемент, а вот onclick его пуст

Comment: А остальные: UP,DOWN,ADD,EDIT -- что? и что должна удалять DEL?